# Stack Overflow for Teams posts by deleted user does not seem to work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have just checked what happens to the content created by a user that I deactivate in Teams. As expected, all content remains and retain the username, but the username is now a s simple text instead of the link to the user's profile. This is OK.

By accessing `https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team}/users/{user_id}/` I can see the following info:

> User was deleted on 3/18/2019 5:50:28 PM User: {user_name} (4)
>   (Account.Id=15555780) deleted by Alex Dragan (1) Reason: Deactivation
>
> Last seen from IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

- a link to the user's posts

**However, when trying to access the posts - `https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts-by-deleted-user/{user_id}` - I receive a 404 error:**

[image: SO for teams search posts by deleted user]

Of course, this is a minor thingy, but it would be nice to work though.

Comment: I think the team part is missing in the second link. What happens when you prepend the /admin of the second link with /c/TEAM/?

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard - yes, you are right. It works, at least in part. The page does not display any of the deleted content you are able to see as admin on the profile when being active. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comment by MEE the setup wizard, you need to add `/c/{team name}` to the URL.
Because when you go to /admin/ pages without the `/c/{team name}` prefix, it thinks that you are trying to access the public Stack Overflow moderator tools.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in the next build, in a couple of ways:

1. The link on the deleted user stub will actually go to the correct place inside the team.
2. That page will *actually display something*. Teams anonymizes content differently than on the main site, but the page was only set up to look for content by deleted users in the way it gets anonymized on the main site (so it would have *always* returned an empty list inside Teams). That's been fixed so it can also find content by deleted users in the Teams context too.

Comment: Downvoter: This is one of those rare cases where an explanation of the downvote would really be useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they don't agree with the solution? Don't want it solved?